# Unlock protection on protected question

Tags: support, protected-questions

Currently, I want to answer the question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/199158/meizu-m3-note-started-lagging-because-of-google-play-services), but it's locked. As my comment was accepted as answer, would you like to unlocked it..?

Answer (score 3):

Done. Please go ahead and post your comment as an answer now. Thank you for asking here instead of taking the easy option by not posting an answer at all.

If you're interested, this particular question was protected because of a flood of "I have the same problem" answers from new visitors.